# Showing that $\lambda(n)|\phi(n)$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer.  Let $\phi(n)$ be the Euler phi function and $\lambda(n)$ be the Carmichael lambda.  I know that $\phi(n)=\phi(2^{t})\phi(p_1^{t_1})\cdots\phi(p_n^{t_n})$.  I also know that for $\lambda(n)=LCM[\lambda(2^t),\phi(p_1^{t_1}),\cdots,\phi(p_n^{t_n})]$ and $\lambda(2^t)$ has three cases.  If $t=1,2$, the $\lambda(2^t)=1,2$. If $t\geq 3$, then $\lambda(2^t)=\phi(2^t)/2$.

Numerically I've demonstrated to myself that this is true.  I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Isn't it just because $lcm(a,b)$ divides $ab$ ?

Comment: My favorite proof of this result relies on the Chinese Remainder Theorem to write $U(n)$, the group of units mod $n$, as a product of the group of units corresponding to the prime factorization of $n$. Then $\lambda(n)$ is the exponent of $U(n)$ and $\phi(n)$ is *one* exponent of $U(n)$ by Lagrange. Then of course $\lambda(n)$ divides $\phi(n)$.

Comment: In the course I'm in we don't have the machinery of Groups.  That would have made the proof nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argue with orders in the multiplicative group of units.