# When is $\lambda (n)$ = $\phi (n)$?

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, carmichael-function

$\lambda (n)$ is the Carmichael function and $\phi (n)$ is the Euler totient function. I can see that if $n$ is prime then the two functions agree and also if $n$ is a power of a prime they agree. Are there any other cases when they agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda (n)$ is the exponent of $U(n)=(\mathbb Z/ n \mathbb Z)^\times$, the group of units mod $n$.

By the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, $U(n)$ has an element of order $\lambda (n)$. Therefore, $\lambda (n)=\phi (n)$ iff $U(n)$ is cyclic, which happens iff $n=1, 2, 4, p^k,2p^k$, where $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Cyclic_case and the last sentence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#General_composite_numbers

Comment: See also your comments in [2014](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749111/showing-that-lambdan-phin-where-n-is-a-positive-integer?rq=1) for divisibility.